# How to represent mixed fractions in java

Tags: java

There is a way to represent fractions over [here](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html). Is there a clear abstraction to represent mixed fractions, so that you can perform addition, subtraction, multiplication operations on it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean by a representation for addition etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Mixed_numbers

Comment: @jzd - I would like to add 1 2/3 + 5 3/7 = 5/3 + 38/7 = 149/21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could perhaps do this by extending `Fraction`: you might want to add a new constructor that takes a whole number in addition to the numerator/denominator `new MixedFraction(2,3,4)` for 2 3/4, and override `toString` to display in the desired format.

Comment: or should I write a separate class MixedFraction which contains a number and a Fraction and implement all the desired methods (e.g. add, subtraction, multiply) on it?

Comment: @Jason: sounds like a perfectly valid solution to me

Comment: Only if you enjoy writing arithmetic code :-) The only reason I could see you'd want to have both an integer & Fraction internally (instead of just an improper fraction) is if you have a requirement to preserve a distinction between (for example) 2 3/4 and 1 7/4.

Answer (score 9):

A mixed fraction is only a display difference and not a mathematical one.  You can just convert it to mixed when you print the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think you can turn it into an improper fraction by adding the fraction part with the integer, do the operations using the methods mentioned in the page you linked to, and transform it back to a mixed fraction by doing this:

```
String turnImproperFractionToMixedFraction(Fraction f) {
    int a = f.getNumerator() / f.getDenominator();
    int b = f.getNumerator() % f.getDenominator();
    return a != 0 ? (a + " " + b + "/" + f.getDenominator()) : (b + "/" + f.getDenominator());
}
```

Using that we can do this:

```
Fraction f = new Fraction(8, 3);
System.out.println(turnImproperFractionToMixedFraction(f));
```

Which should print out `2 2/3`

Comment: I'd throw in a check to avoid like "0 1/2"

Comment: I think the modulus just prints out 2 in this case, you still have to append the "/3"

Comment: @sova good point, my omission, I will modify the code to do that

Answer (score 1):

I think if you keep track of numbers as numerator and denominator (improper fractions - numerators larger than the denominators - as well) it simplifies your task:

```
public class myFraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    ... constructors and methods ...
}
```

Then when you want to do addition and subtraction, you can find the LCD faster, and you can work in one representation.

When you want to display it as a string, you can easily find the number of whole divisions [i.e. floor(numerator/denominator)] and you can find the remainder using either modulus:

```
numerator % denominator + "/" + denominator
```

or you can save the value you get from floor(numerator/denominator) and subtract it from the raw division, which will give you the fractional component (0 <= x < 1), i.e.

```
int myDivision = numerator/denominator;
int myFloor = floor(myDivision);

int fracComponent = myDivision - myFloor; //a number between 0 and 1
int mixedNumerator = fracComponent * denominator; //the numerator of your mixed part
```

the display is then like

```
myFloor + " " + mixedNumerator + "/" + denominator //i.e. 3 1/3
```

A calculator I used a long time ago when learning algebra had a mixed fraction display and showed the answer as **3u1/3** (for "units")

There are several ways where you can decrease your number of operations to get all the facts you want from a number.  Are you doing manipulations on decimal numbers which you must turn into mixed fractions, or are you starting from scratch for input?

I don't know of any Java-based API that has this functionality built-in, but it's not too hard to implement yourself and definitely is a good exercise

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could use `FractionFormat` or `ProperFractionFormat` (in the same Apache Commons package you referenced) to convert between `Fraction` objects and `String` objects representing mixed fractions.

Answer (score 0):

***If you just want your fraction to display as a mixed fraction, try this!***

```
     if ((numer >= denom) & (numer % denom == 0)){
        impFrac = numer / denom;
        System.out.print(numer);
        System.out.print("/"+denom);
        System.out.print(" is an improper fraction, and can be reduced to "+impFrac);
        System.out.println(".");
    }
    else if (numer > denom){
        impFrac = numer / denom;
        mixFrac = numer % denom;
        System.out.print(numer);
        System.out.print("/"+denom);
        System.out.print(" is an improper fraction, and its mixed fraction is "+impFrac);
        System.out.print(" and "+mixFrac);
        System.out.print("/"+denom);
        System.out.println(".");
```