# Converting strings to numbers and back to natural language?

Tags: java, numbers, nlp

I'm working with a recipe database application and I need the ability to convert natural language strings to numbers and vice versa. For example, I need 1 1/4 to convert to 1.25, and I'll need to be able to convert 1.25 back into 1 1/4.

Is there any library or built-in functions that can do this?

Comment: check this [answer](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html)

Comment: That might be very useful, but I still need a conversion tool for the string to number conversion.

Comment: I don't think that's difficult.you can split the string convert the 3 string's to numbers and then pass it to the mixed fraction class.

Comment: Good point, make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: If you don't mind please post the implementation.So that it can be useful for other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270019/how-to-represent-mixed-fractions-in-java) for representing mixed fractions and when you need to convert from the string back to mixed fraction split the string,convert the 3 string's to numbers and pass to the the `MixedFraction` class.

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of in the Java libraries, but there are some online.

Apache has a Fraction class.  Here's it's API
http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/fraction/Fraction.html

The constructor `Fraction(double value)` , `Fraction(int num, int den)` , and the methods `add(Fraction fraction)`  and  `doubleValue()` are what you want, I think.